# CSS div with double border PLUS triange at bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this (triangle at the bottom) in CSS and I'm starting to think it's not possible.

[image: CSS box with double border and triangle bottom]

**Update: got it working - but I do hope there is a better way:**

Layering 4 CSS triangles ontop of eachother using :before :after

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/dtbaker/5fhL1odg/1/

[image: result]

<del>The closest I was able to get is this (using a combination of css triangles that overlap eachother).</del>

[image: my attempt]

<del>Code so far:</del>

http://jsfiddle.net/dtbaker/gk47ggc1/1/

```
<div class="blog">
    <div class="blog_date">
        <span class="month">Sep</span>
        <span class="day">30th</span>
        <span class="year">2014</span>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

div.blog .blog_date {
    z-index: 10;
    top: 10px;
    left: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    width:56px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    color:#4b443a;
    background: #f8f4e9;
    border-top: 2px solid #edebdf;
    border-left: 2px solid #edebdf;
    border-right: 2px solid #edebdf;
}
div.blog .blog_date:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    left:-5px;
    bottom:-5px;
    border-top:1px solid #e8e6da;
    border-left:1px solid #e8e6da;
    border-right:1px solid #e8e6da;
}

div.blog .blog_date div{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 33px 0 33px;
    border-color: #e8e6da transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    z-index: 5;
    left:-5px;
}
div.blog .blog_date div:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 30px 0 30px;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    content: '';
    left: -30px;
    z-index: 3;
}
div.blog .blog_date div:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 30px 0 30px;
    border-color: #f8f4e9 transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    content: '';
    left: -30px;
    z-index: 4;
}

div.blog .blog_date span {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
div.blog .blog_date span.month {
    font-size:13px;
    height:16px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
div.blog .blog_date span.day {
    font-size:18px;
    height:20px;
    color:#c9a976;
}
div.blog .blog_date span.year {
    font-size:13px;
    height:16px;
}
```

It would be very easy via an image, but if some wiz out there can figure this out I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but maybe you can draw the line to form the border of the triangle and play with rotations? Probably won't work on every browser though.

```css
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: got it working - but I do hope there is a better way:

Layering 4 CSS triangles ontop of eachother using :before :after

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/dtbaker/5fhL1odg/1/

[image]

```
div.blog .blog_date {
    z-index: 10;
    left: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    width:56px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    color:#4b443a;
    background: #f8f4e9;
    border-top: 2px solid #edebdf;
    border-left: 2px solid #edebdf;
    border-right: 2px solid #edebdf;
}
div.blog .blog_date:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    left:-5px;
    bottom:-2px;
    border-top:1px solid #e8e6da;
    border-left:1px solid #e8e6da;
    border-right:1px solid #e8e6da;
}
div.blog .blog_date:after {
    /* 1px outer border */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 33px 0 33px;
    border-color: #e8e6da transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    z-index: 2;
    left:-5px;
    content: '';
}
div.blog .blog_date div{
    /* white separator/overlay */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 33px 0 33px;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: 4;
    bottom: -13px;
    left: -5px;
}
div.blog .blog_date div:before {
    /* 2px inner border */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 30px 0 30px;
    border-color: #edebdf transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: 3;
    top: -13px;
    left: -30px;
}
div.blog .blog_date div:after {
    /* inner triangle */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 29px 0 29px;
    border-color: #f8f4e9 transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    content: '';
    left: -29px;
    z-index: 5;
}


div.blog .blog_date span {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
div.blog .blog_date span.month {
    font-size:13px;
    height:16px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
div.blog .blog_date span.day {
    font-size:18px;
    height:20px;
    color:#c9a976;
}
div.blog .blog_date span.year {
    font-size:13px;
    height:16px;
}
```

Comment: better method is to add img in bottom. As this may not work on all browsers, try in IE

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.blog_date{
    font-family: Times New Roman; /*nearly similar to required font */
    width: 100px;
}

div.blog .blog_date span.month {
    float: left; /*added*/
    font-size: 32px;/*changed*/
    height: auto; /*changed*/
    margin-top: 5px;
}

div.blog .blog_date span.day {
    color: #c9a976;
    float: left; /*added*/
    font-size: 34px;/*changed*/
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;/*changed*/
}

div.blog .blog_date span.year {
    float: left; /*added*/
    font-size: 32px;/*changed*/
    height: auto;/*changed*/
}
```

hope this help you.

Comment: I don't think this is what is what he wants to achieve. I think the big problem is the triangle at the bottom which your answer doesn't give an answer to.

Comment: i am not getting you, triangle at bottom?
i think he needs to achieve look appering in 1st img 
while he achieved nearly to 2d one.

Please elaborate if am wrong

Comment: The bottom part of the Picture he achieved looks kinda wrong. He just added a Triangle. It doesn't have a good transition.

Comment: @BhupenderKeswani thank you however the font isn't my issue here. The CSS triangle at the bottom of the div is what I'm stuck on.

Comment: okay then you can add span tag with img inside it of triangle.
assign width to span, and img. then add margin: auto to img, it will work. if this is what you want then lemme know i will create code for you

Comment: @jrenk sorry i wasn't able to get you, its because the screen brightness is kept to very high due to which i wasn't able to see triangle, thanks for reply.